# How to return javascript DOM Element Object, and appendChild(obj) it from caller?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a javascript function drawGrid() that creates a table, rows and cells. 
If I appendChild(table) inside the function, all is well, the table gets displayed.

But I want to return the table and do the appending in the function that calls drawGrid()

Here the end of drawGrid():

```
console.log(table instanceof HTMLElement) // true
console.log(table instanceof Node)        // true
return table;
```

Where I call drawGrid():

```
var table = new Grid()....
console.log(table instanceof HTMLElement) // false
console.log(table instanceof Node)        // false
......appendChild(table);
```

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

How can I return table, so that it arrives still remembering that it is an instanceof Node and HTMLElement, so I can appendChild(table)?

Below the whole code:

```
  function Grid(rows, cols, cellSize, line, thicker, xDivision, yDivision, gridColor, topMargin, opacity) {
    Shape.apply(this, arguments);
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.cellSize = cellSize;
    this.line = line;
    this.thicker = thicker;
    this.xDivision = xDivision;
    this.xAccent = rows/xDivision;
    this.yDivision = yDivision;
    this.yAccent = cols/yDivision;
    this.topMargin = topMargin;
    this.opacity = opacity;
    this.gridColor = gridColor;
    this.drawGrid(this.rows, this.cols, this.cellSize, this.line, this.thicker, this.xAccent, this.yAccent, this.gridColor, this.topMargin, this.opacity);
  };
  Grid.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
  Grid.prototype.constructor = Grid;

  Grid.prototype = {
      drawGrid: function(rows, cols, cellSize, line, thicker, xAccent, yAccent, gridColor, topMargin, opacity) {
          var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
          table.setAttribute("id", "hundred_square");
          table.style.cssText +=';'+ "width: "+ (cols*cellSize) +"vw; height: "+ (rows*cellSize) +"vw; border-collapse: collapse; border: "+ (5*line) +"vw solid" +gridColor+ "; margin: " +topMargin+ "vw auto;";
          for(var i=0; i < rows; i++){
              var row = document.createElement("TR");
              table.appendChild(row);
              row.style.cssText += ';' + "opacity: "+ opacity +"; filter: alpha(opacity="+ (opacity*100) +");";
              for(var j=0; j < cols; j++){
                var cell = document.createElement("TD");
                row.appendChild(cell);
                cell.style.cssText += ';' + "width: "+ cellSize +"vw; height: "+ cellSize +"vw; border-right: "+ (j%yAccent==(yAccent-1) ? thicker*line : line) +"vw solid " +gridColor+ "; border-bottom: "+ (i%xAccent==(xAccent-1) ? thicker*line : line) +"vw solid " +gridColor+ ";opacity: 0."+ opacity +"; filter: alpha(opacity="+ (opacity*100) +");";
              }
          }
          //document.getElementById("js_animation").appendChild(table);
          console.log(table instanceof HTMLElement)   //true
          console.log(table instanceof Node)          //true
          return table;
      }
  };
```

and somewhere else:

```
var table = new sl.Shapes.Grid(10, 10, 3.5, 0.1, 5, 2, 2, "#bfbf8c", 4.5, 0.85);
console.log(table instanceof sl.Shapes.Grid) // true
console.log(table instanceof HTMLElement)    // false
console.log(table instanceof Node)           // false
document.getElementById("js_animation").appendChild(table);
```

Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `table` is `Grid`, not an HTML table itself, and you should use `(new Grid()).drawGrid()` to get the table you can then append to an HTML element.

Comment: Thank you Marat. You pointed me in the right direction, though your answer does not produce the desired result. I needed to remove the drawGrid() function from the constructor, also all the arguments were unnecessary, but the important change was to replace the variables with the prototype versions (not cols, but this.cols) in the drawGrid definition. Now I can return table, say var table = new Grid(..) and then appendChild(table.drawGrid()). Thanks!